Slide div to the left when anchor tag is hover
I want to achieve the same sliding effect on this website, the blue floating button in the right.
What i have is a list item that have anchor and div tag. Div tag would be hidden and would be only visible upon hovering on the anchor tag.
I have manage to achieve it, with the code below but i have this issue where the gap is too wide when the text inside the div is small.

Can anyone help me improve my code, so it would be smooth like in this website.



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  /**
   * Floating menu
   */
  $(".rainbow-floating-menu>li a").hover(
    function() { // Mouse enter
      $(this).siblings(".label").animate({
        left: "-=200px"
      }, 500);
    },
    function() { // Mouse leave
      $(this).siblings(".label").animate({
        left: "+=200px"
      }, 500);
    }
  );
});
.rainbow-floating-menu>li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
}

.rainbow-floating-menu>li a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.rainbow-floating-menu>li div.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: var(--global-palette1);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<li class="get-a-quote">
  <a href="/get-a-quote">
  </a>
  <div class="label">
    <p>Free Estimate Now</p>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="schedule-walkthrough">
  <a href="#">
  </a>
  <div class="label">
    <p>Book Your Walkthrough</p>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">
  </a>
  <div class="label">
    <p>Service Calculator</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="box">
    <div class="header">
      <p>Service Calculator</p>
      <div class="close-btn">
        <picture>
          <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/close-content.webp" alt="close" width=20 height=20>
        </picture>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <?php get_template_part('assets/php/floating-menu-content/service-calculator'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>




Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue.

Can't do much without a demo, but imo you are over-complicate thing. :hover work just fine, no need for jquery here. Combine with transform or position: absolute with right properties and it can do what you want.

The original doesn't use Javascript to move. Both the icon and the text are inside the anchor. When the user hovers over the anchor the text is translated into view. To see this use your browser developer tools.

You do not need script for this tooltip on hover task. What they used is simple CSS, animating the right property. What they had to add is translateX() CSS Function because we do not know the width of the animating DIV and we need to hide it.
For your case you can use the following code:


.rainbow-floating-menu {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 30px;
}

.rainbow-floating-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
}

.rainbow-floating-menu > li a {
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.rainbow-floating-menu > li.get-a-quote a::before {
    content: 'Q';
}

.rainbow-floating-menu > li div.label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lime;
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 10px;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.rainbow-floating-menu > li a:hover + div.label {
    right: 44px;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
<ul class="rainbow-floating-menu">
  <li class="get-a-quote">
    <a href="/get-a-quote"></a>
    <div class="label">Free Estimate Now</div>
  </li>
</ul>



Also at JSFiddle

Solved it using above approach. Thanks!
